# setcookie issue

Tags: php

I'm attempting to set a cookie but the behavior isn't what I'm expecting. I'm thinking that a cookie is much like a session in that the array value will be made immediately available. In the case of this cookie that I've set, the value isn't available immediately and I need to refresh my browser one time to get the value. Is this right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing $_COOKIE immediately after setcookie()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230133/accessing-cookie-immediately-after-setcookie)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's right.

When you set the cookie, you're sending it to the client.  It's not available in the $_COOKIE array until the client sends it back to the server -- in other words not until the *next* page load.

Comment: AWM, I'll credit you for your answer when the 8 minute time constraint expires.