# setcookie does not work (PHP)

Tags: php, setcookie

What's wrong with this code?

```
setcookie("password",$wachtwoord,0, "/", ".thedomainname.com");
echo $_COOKIE['password']; //shows nothing
```

I am attempting to set a cookie and display its value?

Comment: You should not store passwords in cookies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing $_COOKIE immediately after setcookie()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230133/accessing-cookie-immediately-after-setcookie)

Answer (score 3):

Are you waiting for the next request before you examine $_COOKIE ?

Comment: the echo is right after I've set it, but normally the page refreshes and I'm not logged in. When I test it at localhost without the domain setting it works perfectly. So there's something wrong with that part I guess...

Answer (score 3):

$_COOKIE[] with that new cookie will be available only with next request

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the cookie until after you reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code, and worked correctly !

```
<?PHP
setcookie( 'Test' , 'Test' );
echo $_COOKIE['Test'];
?>
```