# setcookie not working

Tags: php, cookies

I know there was a TONS of similar quesitons here, but I've tried already all suggestions posted in other questions, and nothing helped.

This is my function:

```
function makecookie($s, $d) {
    if(empty($_COOKIE[@COOKIE_PATH . "[{$s}]"])) {
        setcookie(@COOKIE_PATH . "[{$s}]", $d);
    }

    return true;
}
```

At the top of the document I got: `ob_start();` and at the end of the document I got `ob_end_flush();`.

When I try:
`echo setcookie(@COOKIE_PATH . "[{$s}]", $d);
exit;`

It returns 1 what means 'true'. And cookie has been not set.

So why does it happen?

Comment: What is `COOKIE_PATH` set to, and what values of `$s` and `$d` are you passing? Are you remembering that the cookie won't be available until the next pageview?

Comment: I assume your question is, "why is there a 1 being returned?", but that's not clear. If that's NOT your question, please clarify.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing $_COOKIE immediately after setcookie()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230133/accessing-cookie-immediately-after-setcookie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the cookie is set, you can retrieve it on next page load with `$_COOKIE["name of cookie"]`

Answer (score 0):

`@COOKIE_PATH` doesn't look like valid/sensible PHP. Are you sure that isn't some sort of typo for (say) `$COOKIE_PATH`?

Comment: @ suppresses errors, and ALL_CAPS generally indicates a constant. `@COOKIE_PATH` is thus perfectly valid PHP. Suppressing errors like that isn't the best idea, though - you won't get a notice pointing out that the constant hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: It is syntactically correct -- I'll give it that. It's still logically crazy, though. :)

Comment: Actually, IMO, it should be `@echo setcookie(COOKIE_PATH . "[{$s}]", $d); exit;` I don't think the @ in front of the constant is correct.