# php cookie doesn't update

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I need to update a cookie. I do that in a php file called via ajax. This is is the code:

```
setcookie('items['.$_POST['id'].']');
```

The cookie does not update, in fact if I write  `print_r($_COOKIE['items'])` after the setcookie function I see that `$_COOKIE['items']` is the same that was before the call to setcookie function. How can I do?

Comment: to retirieve a cookie on a page, the page needs to be refreshed once.

Comment: I hope you cleaned `$_POST['id']` before inserting it in the cookie? `intval($_POST['id'])` will go a long way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing $_COOKIE immediately after setcookie()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230133/accessing-cookie-immediately-after-setcookie)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot set and access a cookie in the same instance/page. You have to do a redirect or refresh after *setting* it.

In addition, you should do something like this instead :

```
setcookie("id","items['.{$_POST['id']}.']");
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `setcookie` is doesn't add the cookie to the superglobal `$_COOKIE`. You will have to do that yourself or reload the page. Also, since you are setting the cookie with an empty value, nothing would be set.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the value for the key to access with `$_COOKIE`:

```
setcookie('items['.$_POST['id'].']', 'some_value');
```

[Link to manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Answer (score 1):

This is syntax for setting a cookie

```
setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain);
```

When you create a cookie, using the function setcookie, **you must specify three arguments**. These arguments are setcookie(name, value, expiration):

1. name: The name of your cookie. You will use this name to later retrieve your cookie, so don't forget it!
2. value: The value that is stored in your cookie. Common values are username(string) and last visit(date).
3. expiration: The date when the cookie will expire and be deleted. If you do not set this expiration date, then it will be treated as a session cookie and be removed when the browser is restarted.

Note:- This will rewrite your cookie not update.

Answer (score 0):

From [php.net/manual/function.setcookie.php](http://php.net/manual/function.setcookie.php):

> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that
>   the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully
>   set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie
>   expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to
>   debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling
>   print_r($_COOKIE);.

So the cookie will be accessible via `$_COOKIE` at the request of the PHP script.