# cookie handling in php

Tags: php, cookies

i get the notice

Notice: Undefined index: date_cook in C:\wamp\www\project work\calendar.php on line 5

when i try to run the following code written in php to handle a calendar :-

```
    <?php
       if(!isset($_COOKIE['date_cook']))
       {
         setcookie('date_cook',0); 
        $date_inc=$_COOKIE['date_cook'];
       }
      else
      {
          if(!isset($_POST['nxt']))
         {
            $date_inc=$_COOKIE['date_cook'];
         }
         else
         {
            $date_inc=$_COOKIE['date_cook'];
            $date_inc++;
            setcookie('date_cook',$date_inc);
            unset($_POST['nxt']);
         }  
       }
      ?>//the calendar code follows here after.
```

the notice is displayed for line number 5 of the code
 can somebody tell me where did i go wrong...??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing $\_COOKIE immediately after setcookie()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230133/accessing-cookie-immediately-after-setcookie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you `setcookie()`, it's not instantly stored in $_COOKIE. You either have to put it there manually (`$_COOKIE['date_cook'] = 0`) or use a variable instead.

Comment: thanx for your instant reply ....but hten if it is so ...what really is the use of the function setcookie ?

Comment: It sets the cookie for the next pageview. The next time the script is invoked it will be available.

Comment: ok there's another problem with the code. so i have a submit button named 'nxt' in my form. on submit i go to the same page again that contains the above code and i check if the 'nxt' button was pressed or not. if it was i fetch the value of the cookie set earlier, increment it and set it back into the same cookie. but on clicking on the next button , it doesn't work.

Comment: You're modifying a `$_` variable. This is generally a bad idea (even directly after `setcookie()` it can be dangerous). Try finding an alternate approach to your case - just don't modify the globals :)

Comment: So you mean even if i set the value of a $_ superglobal manually, i still have to use setcookie() ?  I just tried debugging, inserted an echo immediately after the first else, just before if(!isset($_POST['nxt'])), and it did not get echoed out, showing that the control did not really enter the else part. Any suggestions..??

Comment: The code probably entered one if-block and you probably changed something that would've changed the outcome of the if-statement. You are probably expecting that the if-statement is reevaluated and the interpreter will enter the second loop. **This will never happen: statements aren't evaluated twice**. It either enters the *if* part, or it enters the *else* part, but it won't go from *if* to *else*.

Comment: Ok, so here is what i actually need to do. I have a calendar on ,my page. It has a next button on it. Now when the user presses the next button he should be redirected to this same script again( the one that displays the initial calendar). But this time this time and every time the user presses the next button, i want a variable to be incremented. Then i plan to add this incremented variable to the variable that holds the current month(extracted using the date()), so that when user presses the next button he shall get the calendar for the next month. Can u suggest any way i can achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you just use a $_GET variable which holds the current page number?

Comment: but how am i going to pass the incremented value to this page?

Comment: That is called Pagination. Basically you would assign the button a variable (example: `<a href="posts.php?page=1">`) and increment this before actually going there. Eg. on page 1 you get a link pointing at page 2, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help dude. It was really really helpful. I shall try doing it and some digging around. If i am unable to do it, i shall come back to you again for help,. Hope you won't mind that. Please let me know your email id for furtherer communication, if possible. This is my id.. abhinav.mr.impractical@gmail.com. Thanks again.