# Receiving error after setting a cookie and calling it

Tags: php, cookies, multilingual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing $_COOKIE immediately after setcookie()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230133/accessing-cookie-immediately-after-setcookie)

So I am using the following code below to add multilingual features to my site:

```
if(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] != ""){
setcookie("lang", $lang, time()+360*360*3600);
}elseif(!isset($_COOKIE["lang"]) || $_COOKIE["lang"] == ""){
setcookie("lang", "en", time()+360*360*3600);
}
include 'lang/'.$_COOKIE["lang"].'.php';
```

Now when this code gets executed the first time it fails to find the `$_COOKIE["lang"] and therefore fails to open the file, however after when I refresh the page it loads just fine.
I was wondering what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Consider performing some validation on `$_COOKIE["lang"]` before dropping it into an `include` statement to avoid a [path traversal attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal).

Answer (score 2):

The cookie is only set when you do a request.

That's how it works (it is send with every request). And since you are still in the same request it simply isn't there yet.

But you can set it your own:

```
if (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] != "") {
    $_COOKIE['lang'] = $lang;
    setcookie("lang", $lang, time()+360*360*3600);
} elseif ...
```

That's maybe the work-around you're looking for.