# After submit page shows old value of $_COOKIE[] until next refresh

Tags: php, html

I am having an issue where after first clicking Submit, and the page reloads, the page shows the old value for each cookie set until the page is refreshed or reloaded.

Here is essentially how I have it set up.

index.php

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['filter'])){
        foreach($_POST['filter'] as $key=>$value){
            $xNums[] = $key;    
        }
        $vals = $_POST['filter'];
        updateFilter($vals, $xNums);
    }
?>
<form action='index.php' method='post'>
<input type='radio' name=filter['".$xNum."'] value='yes' />Show<input type='radio' name=filter['".$SomeVariable."'] value='no' />Hide
<input type=submit value=" Submit " />
<?php
    echo displayStatus($xNum);
?>
```

functions.php

```
function updateFilter($vals, $xNums){
    foreach($xNums as $xNum){
        $val = $vals[$xNum];
        setcookie($xNum, $val, time()+3600);
    }
    return;
}

function displayStatus($xNum){
    if($_COOKIE["'".$xNum."'"]=='no'){
        return "no";
    } else {
        return "yes";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cookie which you set using `setcookie` is not visible by PHP script in `$_COOKIES` superglobal variable until next request because `setcookie` only set `Set-Cookie` header in http response.

If you want to read these cookies in the same request you can use:

```
setcookie($xNum, $val, time()+3600);
$_COOKIE[$xNum] = $val;
```

edit: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230133/accessing-cookie-immediately-after-setcookie) is similar problem.