# Accessing cookie immediately after setting it

Tags: php, cookies

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3230164/1252748) makes it seem like I should immediately be able to access a cookie after creating it if I specify its name:

```
$username = "thomas";

setcookie("logs_sign_in", $username, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, ".");

echo var_dump($_COOKIE['logs_sign_in']);
```

However I still get `NULL`. I only the name after I refresh the page. Why is this?

Comment: Since it is the first related post, it probably came up as a suggestion when you were asking yours. They are there for a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply how cookies work:

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the `$_COOKIE` or `$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS` arrays. [(`setcookie` manual page)](http://php.net/setcookie)

This actually makes a great deal of sense. Look at the manual page for `$_COOKIE`:

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via HTTP Cookies.

The value wasn't passed to the current script via HTTP Cookies, so it isn't in the `$_COOKIE` array.