# Why can't I set a cookie in my Paypal IPN file

Tags: javascript, php, paypal-ipn, setcookie

My Paypal ipn file works fine - once verified I can add the payer to my sql database and write to a log file on my server, but setcookie doesn't seem to work. I want to simply set a flag so I know this person has paid.
How else can I set a flag so my Javascript code knows they have paid?

Comment: setcookie set the cookies only after a page loading (If I remember correctly). That may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: You could chuck it into the session, then in your JS have something like `var isPaid = <?= !empty($_SESSION['paid']) ? "true" : "false"; ?>;` - it's a bit dirty but should do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IPN request is made by a PayPal server, not by the user's web browser. You can't set cookies in a user agent that didn't make a request!

To use PayPal for a membership system, you need to do a couple of things:

- Have a user login system that uses a database. Hopefully you have this already! Include a column for having paid in the database table which contains users.
- Include some data in the payment which identifies the user that's paying. For instance, include the user's ID in the `invoice` field.
- When you receive a verified IPN, read the user's ID out of the `invoice` field and update the appropriate row in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, if it really is the server that does not set cookies before your check :

```
setcookie('uname', $uname, time()+60*30);
$_COOKIE['uname'] = $uname;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3230167/7924393

If it can help.

Comment: No, that doesn't help at all. As I mentioned in my answer, the IPN request is being made by the wrong agent entirely -- cookies won't work for this at all.