# Logic behind the code?

Tags: php

There are two blocks of PHP code

Block 1

```
<?php
setcookie("test_cookie","0",time()-3600);
if(empty($_COOKIE["test_cookie"])){
    echo "First time browsing";
    setcookie("test_cookie","1",time()+3600);
}else{
    $count = $_COOKIE['test_cookie'];
    $count++;
    setcookie("test_cookie",$count,time()+3600);
    echo "Cookie set as " . $_COOKIE["test_cookie"] ;
}
```

Block 2

```
<?php
if(empty($_COOKIE["test_cookie"])){
    echo "First time browsing";
    setcookie("test_cookie","1",time()+3600);
}else{
    $count = $_COOKIE['test_cookie'];
    $count++;
    setcookie("test_cookie",$count,time()+3600);
    echo "Cookie set as " . $_COOKIE["test_cookie"] ;
}
    setcookie("test_cookie","0",time()-3600);
```

In Block 1 cookie named test is unset which should echo "first time browsing"
but what i get is cookie count

In block 2 cookie named test is unset at last which echo "first time browsing" which is fine and i understand logic no matter what i set i unset at last which results in "first time browsing"

But what is wrong with with Block 1 i should have got same result as BLock 2 .. why am i  getting Cookie count here ? 
Please do explain this in simplest way possible .

Comment: From [documentation of `setcookie()`](http://php.net/setcookie): _"Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the **next page load** with the $_COOKIE array"_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing $\_COOKIE immediately after setcookie()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230133/accessing-cookie-immediately-after-setcookie)

Answer (score 0):

The `setcookie` function does not modify the `$_COOKIE` array. It just state changes, that will be sent to the client. Your changes will be available in the `$_COOKIE` array only on the next page loads.

If you want the `$_COOKIE` array to be up to date with your `setcookie` calls in the current request, you should updates it manually every time:

```
setcookie("test_cookie","0",time()-3600);
unset($_COOKIE["test_cookie"]);

setcookie("test_cookie","1",time()+3600);
$_COOKIE["test_cookie"] = "1";
```

Also calling `setcookie` after any output, as in your code, may lead to errors.