# setcookie() does not set cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I have an internal network running XAMPP. I am trying to set a cookie for an item when someone logs in. I use the following code. `$Access` will be a 1 if user authenticates correctly. When a user enters their username and password it passes to a CheckAuth page with the following code.

```
$Access = authenticateUser($_POST['Username'],$_POST['Password']);
setcookie("Access", $Access, time()+3600);
header('Location:Newpage.php');
```

On the NewPage it if I do a `$_COOKIE['Access']` it will show me 1 and set everything correctly. If I click a link to another page, say Inventory.php, within the same folder, `$_COOKIE['Access']` shows 0 instead of 1.

What could be the issue that the cookie is magically gone? I have checked the IE files for the cookie when it is made and it doesn't show up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing $\_COOKIE immediately after setcookie()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230133/accessing-cookie-immediately-after-setcookie)

Comment: @JAAulde that link does not help me. I am setting a cookie with the correct code but it can't doesn't actually set. Meaning I am trying to set the cookie on this page. And then on the next page I recall it and it should have 1. Instead it has nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The super global, `$_COOKIE`, *only* contains cookies that were given by the browser to the server in the incoming Request.

`setcookie()` only sets up HTTP headers for the outgoing Response that will instruct the browser to set a cookie.

If you want this cookie to be available in `$_COOKIE`, you'll need to set it manually at the same time as you call `set_cookie()`:

```
setcookie('Access', $Access);
$_COOKIE['Access'] = $Access;
```

Comment: So if I set it with $_COOKIE['Access'] and then try and check it on a page in the same folder it says $_COOKIE['Access'] is 0. Does it not pass through pages?

Comment: You have to do both

Comment: I have done both and the cookie does not hold. I don't even see the cookie in the internet files where it would be stored.

Answer (score -1):

```
$Access = authenticateUser($_POST['Username],$_POST['Password']);
```

Missing a quote after $_POST['Username

```
$Access = authenticateUser($_POST['Username'],$_POST['Password']);
```

Comment: That was likely a typo in the question and not an actual code problem. Else there'd be a fatal error displayed and the question would be about that.

Comment: Ah okay, my apologies! Thanks for letting me know